# How can I remove plot margins between the axes of the plot and the plot contents in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to remove the space between the axes of the plot and the plot contents themselves. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the parameters `xaxs` and `yaxs` (under `?par`).  By default the axis contains the data range plus 4% on either side.  If you override the parameter, then you can get an axis exactly equal to the data range.  Cf:

```
> curve(x^2)

> curve(x^2, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

Comment: it still doesn't appear to completely work, i still some space on the y side but i think this is also a relatively new feature. Thanks though.